# php joomla k2 code suggestion

Tags: php, joomla2.5

i'm working with k2, the joomla content module.
i'm using extra fields and i have a particular need. 
i associated some link type extra fields to a k2 category: 
i need them to be invisible to users while they create items from frontend, 
but then come back visible after i (administrator) filled those fields from backend. 
so i just need to hide those extrafields (all the link type) from the itemform view: below is the code where i should add something like 
IF 
 
THEN 
 
ELSE 
 
END 
but i don't know nothing about php code compiling... can any body suggest something???

CODE:

```
<table class="admintable" id="extraFields"> 
<?php foreach($this->extraFields as $extraField): ?> 
<tr> 
<td align="right" class="key"> 
<?php echo $extraField->name; ?> 
</td> 
<td> 
<?php echo $extraField->element; ?> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that code to this -

```
<table class="admintable" id="extraFields"> 
<?php foreach($this->extraFields as $extraField): ?> 
<?php if ($extrafield->name !="name of field you want to hide") { ?>
<tr> 
<td align="right" class="key"> 
<?php echo $extraField->name; ?> 
</td> 
<td> 
<?php echo $extraField->element; ?> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

Be sure to do it as a template override so it doesn't get killed when you update.

Comment: looks simple but it's not working. about override: this is a plugin, the file i'm editing is in the folder ...\plugins\system\k2multiimages\K2MultiImages\administrator\templates so where shoud i create and put the new override file??? thanks

Comment: the correct folder should then be: root\templates\default template\html\K2MultiImages\administrator\default.php